# How do you make a wrapped div fill the window horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is contained by another 960px-wide centered div. I'm adding a background to the inner div which should expand all the way to the window's edges horizontally, essentially escaping the boundaries of its container. If I apply a large negative margin and equal amount of padding, this works on the left side, but the right side causes a scroll bar to appear. Does anyone know how I can achieve this without causing scroll bars?

Comment: Why do you want the INNER div's background to stretch to fill out the entire window?  It seems like you would want to do this with the OUTER div.  Did I understand the question correctly?

Comment: Yes, normally I would do that, but this is for a Wordpress theme, and the content is wrapped by that outer div. The inner div is within the content and there are other elements within the content that will not have the background. I hope I've explained myself correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone, but most of these solutions just created more difficulties positioning elements further down the page. I ended up taking a different approach and pulling the div that needed the background out of the wrapper div. It's not ideal because now I can't display any of the post content in that inner div, but it'll work. Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You could position the inner div absolutely:

CSS

```
.outerdiv { width: 960px; background: #999; height: 50px; }
.innerdiv { position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 0; background: #ccc; width: 100%; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="outerdiv">This is in the outer div
 <div class="innerdiv">This is in the inner div</div>
</div>
```

or better yet, move the div to have the document body as it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

I always put my overlay DIV outside of the content wrapper, that way it is not constrained by the layout.

If you're boxed-in (no pun intended) you can add this DIV using JavaScript, putting it wherever in the DOM you want.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the outer div is set to (or inheriting) overflow:auto rather than overflow:visible.